# Using the original values of a vector after manipulation

Tags: c++, vector

I am trying to convert vector values that are received form a file into two different formats. After converting into first format and printing the vector out, I want to use the original "read in" values to convert them into the second format.

At the moment, it seems that the second conversion is happening on the already converted values. However, I don't understand why it doesn't convert back to the original value then? And ultimately, how can I use the original values of the vector for the second conversion so the

```
else {
        GetType();
        GetXArg();
        GetYArg();
    }
```

works for the second time?

Here is the code snippet:

```
void Force::convToP()  //converts to polar
{
    if (forceType == 'c')
    {
        SetType('p');
        SetXArg(sqrt(xArg * xArg + yArg * yArg));
        SetYArg(atan(yArg / xArg));
    }
    else {
        GetType();  //just return type, xArg and yArg in their original form
        GetXArg();
        GetYArg();
    }

}

void Force::convToC()  //converts to cartesian
{
    if (forceType == 'p') {
        SetType('c');
        SetXArg(xArg * cos(yArg));
        SetYArg(xArg * sin(yArg));
    }
    else {
        GetType();
        GetXArg();
        GetYArg();
    }
}
```

and the main function:

```
while (file >> type >> x >> y) {
        Force f(type, x, y);
        force.push_back(f);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < force.size(); ++i) {
        force[i].printforce();
    }

    cout << "Forces in Polar form: " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < force.size(); ++i)
    {
        force[i].convToP();
        force[i].printforce();
    }

    cout << "Forces in Cartesian form: " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < force.size(); ++i) {
        force[i].convToC();
        force[i].printforce();
    }
```

finally, the output at the moment is:

```
p 10 0.5
c 12 14
p 25 1
p 100 0.8
c 50 50
p 20 3.14
c -100 25
p 12 1.14

Forces in Polar form:  <-first conversion. All works fine

p 10 0.5  
p 18.4391 0.649399
p 25 1
p 100 0.8
p 70.7107 0.61548
p 20 3.14
p 103.078 0.237941
p 12 1.14

Forces in Cartesian form:

c 8.77583 4.20736 <-works fine
c 14.6858 8.8806  <-why doesn't convert back to c 12 14/ how to use the original values of vector
c 13.5076 11.3662
c 69.6707 49.9787
c 57.735 33.3333
c -20 -0.0318509
c 100.173 23.6111
c 5.01113 4.55328
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Very new to this, been baffled for some time, so would really appreciate any help and advice.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. For example in your code it isnt clear what all those `GetXArg();` are doing. Btw if you do something like `a = foo(a);` how would you get the original value of `a` ?

Comment: @user463035818 all the `Get` functions just return the `xArg`, `yArg` and `fType`

Comment: yes, i saw the comment, but that confuses me even more, because if those `Get` functions return something then you just ignore the returned value....

Comment: An MCVE is not 'here are some fragments of code and colloquial descriptions of what the missing bits do'.

Comment: By manually checking `c 50 50`, you got `p 70.7107 0.61548` but `atan(1)` is `0.785398`...

Comment: @underscore_d my bad, will work on my MCVEs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are modifying `xArg` and then using the modified value to convert `yArg`. You need to do both conversions before either modification.

```
void Force::convToP()  //converts to polar
{
    if (forceType == 'c')
    {
        forceType = 'p';
        decltype(xArg) newX = sqrt(xArg * xArg + yArg * yArg);
        decltype(yArg) newY = atan(yArg / xArg);
        xArg = newX;
        yArg = newY
    }
    // no else needed
}

void Force::convToC()  //converts to cartesian
{
    if (forceType == 'p') {
        forceType = 'c';
        decltype(xArg) newX = xArg * cos(yArg);
        decltype(yArg) newY = xArg * sin(yArg);
        xArg = newX;
        yArg = newY
    }
    // no else needed
}
```

You can verify [the correct values](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6ae1b61d25d7cbe2) with [`std::complex`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex)

```
#include <complex>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main() {

    std::vector<std::complex<double>> nums
    {
        std::polar<double>(10, 0.5),
        std::complex<double>(12, 14),
        std::polar<double>(25, 1),
        std::polar<double>(100, 0.8),
        std::complex<double>(50, 50),
        std::polar<double>(20, 3.14),
        std::complex<double>(-100, 25),
        std::polar<double>(12, 1.14)
    };

    for (auto num : nums) 
    { 
        std::cout << num << " (" << std::abs(num) << ", " << std::arg(num) << ")\n";
    }
}
```

> ```
> (8.77583,4.79426) (10, 0.5)
> (12,14) (18.4391, 0.86217)
> (13.5076,21.0368) (25, 1)
> (69.6707,71.7356) (100, 0.8)
> (50,50) (70.7107, 0.785398)
> (-20,0.0318531) (20, 3.14)
> (-100,25) (103.078, 2.89661)
> (5.01113,10.9036) (12, 1.14)
> ```

Comment: Well done for finding that `All works fine` in first conversion was in error

Comment: @UKMonkey My guess is OP looked at the numbers and saw "Here are some decimals, that must be correct", and didn't independently check

Comment: @Caleth @UKMonkey  was too busy to see how to use the originals, to notice that the `xArg` was being modified before second use. Format wise looked fine, so didn't click. Thank you for noticing the error

Answer (score 1):

It's often helpful to break sub-operations down into small single-concern functions.

The compiler will optimise away all the redundant copies, loads and stores:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <tuple>

auto computed(double xArg, double yArg) 
{
    return 
        std::make_tuple(
            std::sqrt(xArg * xArg + yArg * yArg),
            std::atan(yArg / xArg));
}

void modify(double& xArg, double& yArg)
{
    std::tie(xArg, yArg) = computed(xArg, yArg);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your conversion function obviously changes the object it operates on. Then you need to be aware that the index operator (`[]`) returns a *reference* to the object in the vector. If you do not want to modify the original object, you'll have to make a copy of:

```
for (int i = 0; i < force.size(); ++i)
{
    auto copy = force[i]
    copy.convToP();
    copy.printforce();
}
```

Now, you can operate on the unchanged values in the second run. Assuming you don't need the original values afterwards any more, you can just leave the second loop as is, otherwise, make copies again...

All a little easier with range based for loop:

```
for(auto c : force)
{
    c.convToP();
    c.printforce();
}

for(auto& c : force)
//      ^ if you don't need original values any more, can use reference now
{
    c.convToC();
    c.printforce();
}
```

Comment: As a safety check, it's probably a good idea to also add a `const` overload of `operator[]`, and then use range-based `for` loops to operate on `const` objects.  That way, if you accidentally try to modify them, it will fail to compile.

Comment: @0x5453 Then how would you expect the `convToX()` functions to work?

Comment: @MaxLanghof See my edit.  He still needs to make copies, but this way the compiler will enforce that he cannot modify the original objects.

Comment: @Aconcagua thank you so much, that gives me exactly what i was looking for, but didn't know how to do!

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing exactly what `GetXArg()` etc. do, it appears that you are modifying your original forces when you call `force[i].convToP();`. So after this loop all the forces in your array are converted to polar. If all you want to do is print the polar and cartesian representations *without* changing the originals, you should generate copies of the forces:

```
cout << "Forces in Polar form: " << endl;
for (int i = 0; i < force.size(); ++i)
{
    Force tmpForce = force[i];
    tmpForce.convToP();
    tmpForce.printforce();
}
```

etc.

Edit: Looks like @Aconcagua beat me to it.